How do I migrate Eclipse Classpath File Entries to Gradle or Intellij?
I'm working on this new project where the eclipse .classpath file is stored in the repo. I imported my project into IntelliJ as a gradle project as there is a build.gradle file. When I build the project all my class files and build output is added to an out directory.
When I compare with my teammates build files, their files are sent to what is written in the class path file, in the build directory.
In getting the build files in the right directory my teammates suggested I run gradle clean build, which I did, but the output directory didn't change.
I'm not sure if this is IntelliJ being smart or I just need to use Eclipse as my IDE, but I am curious if there is a way to change the gradle settings or IntelliJ settings so that the class path entries are honored when running a gradle build.

And does it work if you build using Gradle commands from the command line? If so, you are not delegating the build in IntelliJ to Gradle. Otherwise, you are setting the build output directory to "out" somewhere in your build.
